# Finding k using Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a swamp there are two regular frogs and three princes frogs, the queen take out $k$ frogs with return. Let $R$ be the number of times that regular frog took out.

> Evaluate the minimal number k such that the probabilty to take out regular froge at the most  $50\%$ from the tooks out will be at least $0.99$ using Chebyshev's inequality

My attempt:

$R\sim B(n,p)\;\;\;,\;\;\;$ 
$R\sim B(k,\frac25)\;\;\;,\;\;\;$
$E[R]=\boxed{\frac{2k}{5}}\;\;\;\;,\;\;\;\;\;$
Var$[R]=\boxed{\frac{6k}{25}}$

$$P(|R-E[R]| \geq \alpha)\leq \frac{\text{Var}(R)}{\alpha ^2}$$

$$P\big(\big|R-\frac{2k}{5}\big| \geq \alpha\big)\leq \frac{6k}{25 \alpha ^2}$$

> Is it correct so far? I don't know how to proceed, hints please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $\dfrac{k}{2} - \dfrac{2k}{5} = \dfrac{k}{10}$
- $1-0.99 = 0.01$

so see what you should use for $\alpha$, and so what $k$ should be.

Comment: Not relevant to finding the answer to the question as asked, but the resulting $k$ using Chebyshev's inequality is about $18$ to $20$ times as large as the result you could get from the binomial distribution.

Comment: $P\bigg(R-\frac{2k}{5}\geq \frac{k}{10}\bigg)\leq \frac{600}{25k}$ how can I proceed?

Comment: $0.01\leq \frac{600}{25k},\;\;\;\;k\leq 2400$ is it correct?

Comment: @Nehorai: Yes - I think $2400$  is the expected result except that the inequality is reversed  so $k \ge 2400$.  Earlier you wanted $ P\bigg(R-\frac{2k}{5} \geq \frac{k}{10}\bigg)\leq 0.01$ which is true if $\frac{600}{25k}\le 0.01$.

Comment: Using R and the binomial distribution `which(pbinom((1:150)/2, size=1:150, prob=2/5) >= 0.99)` the true cases are $k=122,124,126,128,  130$ or $k \ge 132$.  This shows that $k\ge 2400$ is a very weak result, as often happens with Chebyshev's inequality.